# Open hashing, add element, and find element using iterator

Tags: c++, hash

I have an open hash table using the STL.

```
typedef std::list<int> LIST;
typedef std::vector<LIST> HASH_TABLE;
```

I initialized the hash table by filling it with empty lists.

```
LIST mt_list;
HASH_TABLE hTable;
hTable.assign(7, mt_list);
```

Now if I want to add an int to my table based on:

```
hKey = (value*value) % 7;
```

and I use

```
hTable[hKey].push_back(value);
```

It should work right?  I can't get it to work.

```
void addValue(int value){
    if(val_find(value)){
        std::cout << "WARNING: duplicate input: " << value << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        calc_hash_bucket(value);        //set hKey
        hTable[hKey].push_back(value);  //push value into list
    }
}
```

The code above does not add the element to any of the lists within the vector.

Also, when I want to use an iterator to traverse the vector and the lists within the vector, how do I get one element at a time from a list so I can find a particular value that may or may not already be in the list?

This is what I have for finding a value within the hash table:

```
bool val_find(int value){
    if(mt_hash()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        for(HASH_ITER h_iter = hTable.begin(); h_iter != hTable.end(); ++h_iter){
            for(LIST_ITER l_iter = h_iter->begin(); l_iter != h_iter->end(); ++l_iter){
                if(*l_iter == value){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm stumped. I don't understand why it won't add the value to any of the lists.

I feel I should mention this is all in a header file and part of a class that I created. (I don't know if that matters)

Edit: The warning statement does not print. To answer questions, the mt_hash() function checks to see if the hash table is empty and I have checked it several times to make sure it outputs correctly. I fixed the hTable_1 vs hTable difference, they are the same thing. I just forgot to change it when I put it into the question.

```
bool mt_hash(void){    //is hash table empty?
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hTable.size(); ++i){
        if(!hTable.at(i).empty()){ //if not empty return false
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    //else return true
}
```

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: There's a lot of global state that you aren't showing us. This means there are many possible issues. Is `mt_hash()` implemented correctly? Why do you say `hTable` in `addValue` and `hTable_t` in `val_find`? BTW this should be very easy to figure out with a debugger.

Comment: I am using ubuntu and geany. I have code::blocks but the debugger isn't working properly. I havent tried gdb yet. You are right, I need to just give in and use gdb in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

As Pradhan points out, there is a quite a bit missing. What is the implementation of `mt_hash()`? Are `hTable_1` and `hTable` the same object?

Below, I've taken your code above, and placed them in a struct with the implied functionality included. Note three changes: `hTable` replaces `hTable_1` in `val_find()`; `addValue()` uses a local variable to store the hash key; and `mt_hash()` is implemented by keeping a simple element count.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct open_hash {
    typedef std::list<int> LIST;
    typedef std::vector<LIST> HASH_TABLE;

    typedef LIST::const_iterator LIST_ITER;
    typedef HASH_TABLE::const_iterator HASH_ITER;

    HASH_TABLE hTable;
    int nbins;
    int elem_count;

    explicit open_hash(int nbins_): nbins(nbins_), elem_count(0) {
        init_hash();
    }

    void init_hash() {
        LIST mt_list;
        hTable.assign(nbins, mt_list);
    }

    int hash_bucket(int value) const {
        return (value*value)%nbins;
    }

    bool mt_hash() const {
        return elem_count==0;
    }

    bool val_find(int value) const {
        if (mt_hash()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (HASH_ITER h_iter = hTable.begin(); h_iter != hTable.end(); ++h_iter){
            for (LIST_ITER l_iter = h_iter->begin(); l_iter != h_iter->end(); ++l_iter){
                if (*l_iter == value) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void addValue(int value) {
        if (val_find(value)) {
            std::cout << "WARNING: duplicate input: " << value << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            int hKey=hash_bucket(value);
            hTable[hKey].push_back(value);  //push value into list
            ++elem_count;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    open_hash H(7);
    std::vector<int> vals={3,1,9,2,10,4,3};

    for (int v: vals) {
        H.addValue(v);
    }

    for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "val_find(" << i << "):\t" << std::boolalpha << H.val_find(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

This produces expected output:

```
WARNING: duplicate input: 3
val_find(1):    true
val_find(2):    true
val_find(3):    true
val_find(4):    true
val_find(5):    false
val_find(6):    false
val_find(7):    false
val_find(8):    false
val_find(9):    true
val_find(10):   true
```

I suspect the original problem lies in `addValue()` and `val_find()` referring to different hash objects, or a problem in `mt_hash()` misreporting that the table is empty when in fact it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the this problem is to create the class object of type HASH_TABLE in the main cpp file and then pass it by reference into the function (getCmd) that calls all of the commands and i/o.

I was calling the "getCmd" function in main() and that function (EVERY time it is called) creates a NEW instance of the HASH_TABLE class, effectively "replacing" the previous object with a new, empty object. (though I suspect it did not actually replace the previous object. I think the previous object was still taking up memory but it was not being used)

I didn't post the code for the problem area because I didn't know where the problem was.

Thanks for all your help!